# Stop newline submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser

I have a slightly unusual form-related problem. My web app listens for scanner input from a barcode reader. The barcode reader presents as keyboard input in the following format:

```
~100.0101~\n
```

where `\n` is a newline. I use a global javascript listener with a regex - whenever the listener 'hears' input that matches the regex, I call my `barcodeHandler()` function.

Unfortunately, this doesn't interact well with forms: if the user is focussed on a form input when they scan, the form is submitted and posts back before the listener kicks in, because the form takes `\n` to mean 'submit'.

I can't change the scanner input, so is there any way I can stop the forms submitting when the `\n` is entered?

Obviously, I'd still like my forms to work with the Enter key, and I'd rather not change the default form behaviour if possible!

many thanks!

Comment: you can use jquery and assign a special function on key actions and do event.preventdefault(); to prevent the "enter" key from being processed as a submit of the form.

Comment: Thanks - though I'd really like the Enter key still to work - just not the `\n` supplied by the barcode scanner. Is there a way to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Ah, I can just apply the event listener when the first part of the regex has been matched. That works.

Comment: FYI: a < textarea > will not submit forms with the newline ( \n ) from a barcode readers input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to capture the keypress on form controls and prevent the default action using `preventDefault()` or `return false`.

```
// do this for all <input> <textarea> and <select> elements on the page.
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event){
    if (event.which == '10' || event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

or using jQuery:

```
$("input, textarea, select").keypress(function(event){
    if (event.which == '10' || event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: works like a charm! I used like this: `$(":input").keypress( //code )` because i wanted to capture this on all inputs. thanks. +1

Answer (score 3):

Override the form's onsubmit and supply your own alternative as an onclick handler on the submit button.

```
<form action="submit.php" onsubmit="return false;">
    Some input ...<input type="text"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="parentNode.submit();">
</form>
```